# Umbraco MVC Check is Partial has content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I've got a template on Umbraco, I've setup a Partial View that checks if there is a Hero Unit selected for the page.
I want to check if this Partial is sending any content into the page, if it isn't I want to render 1 div, if there is a hero unit selected, I want 2 divs.

My code currently is;

```
var heroUnit = @Html.Partial("HeroUnits",@Model.Content);
    @if(heroUnit != null)
    {
        <div class="span6">
            @Html.Raw(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("bodyText"))
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            @Html.Partial("HeroUnits",@Model.Content);
        </div>      
    } else {
        <div class="span9">
            @Html.Raw(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("bodyText"))
        </div>
    }
```

This code seems to think that HeroUnit is always null.

Comment: I've added an answer that will probably help you in the event you still have this issue or in future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be with jquery, you have a wrapper div where you drop the content of your partial into, using jquery on load you check of the content of the div is empty, if it is then render the other 2 div's else render the one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe partials are used in this way.  Because it seems like you are trying to get a scalar value out of the function I think a helper function is your best bet and can be used globally throughout your app.

Add a file to App_code:  HeroHelper.cshtml

Then create your function:

```
@using Umbraco
@using Umbraco.Core
@using Umbraco.Web.Models;
@using Umbraco.Core.Media;
@using Umbraco.Core.Models;
@using Umbraco.Web;
@using Umbraco.Web.umbraco;
@functions {

   public static bool HasHero(IPublishedContentNode node) 
   {
       // this contains your logic, I'll make somethingup
        return node.HasValue("HereUnit");       
   }
}
```

Now the following will work: `var heroUnit = HeroHelper.HasHero(Model.Content);`

You could furthermore create an html helper for this but this just depends on your use case.  This helper function or set of functions you'd use in your partial as well to keep it all consistent.